# How to apply data into useState constant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, use-state

I was trying to set a value to a input, and I usead setState to update the value of the Input, but now I cant use the variable I was going to use in the Value inside Input.

This is the Input

```
<input
type="text"
className="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-[#604d9b] block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
value={name}
placeholder="Type any name you want"
onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

and this is my hook.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
```

Now, I want to apply this variable but I cant do it directly to the constant inside the useState

```
userData[0]?.name;
```

Anyone knows how to apply my

```
userData[0]?.name;
```

Into

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
```

Comment: Hey you want to set userData[0]?.name in the name hook? onChange of input or initial value?...can you reframe you question it is not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useEffect to handle this kind of problems:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(userData[0]?.name){
      setName(userData[0]?.name)
    }
 },[userData])
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I will try to study useEffect

Comment: @Nathan Your welcome, for sure useEffect function is a very important topic in React world.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to set the initial value for your `name` state.

If this is the case, you can simply pass it as an argument to `useState`:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState(userData[0]?.name || '');
```